# How to roll Series elements on non overlapping intervals

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I'd like to calculate rolling sum of elements as R rollapply doing:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

As result I'd like to receive new series with sum of elements for non overlapping intervals(window size is 2):

```
3
7
11
```

Pandas Series.rolling procedure works in other way producing rolling on overlapping intervals. Please tell me how to do what I want...

Comment: `s.rolling(2).sum().iloc[1::2]`?

Comment: No, it returns wrong result...

Comment: What did you get? I get `3 7 11`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
s.groupby(s.index//2).sum()
0     3
1     7
2    11
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is true solution:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
pd.Series([np.sum(s[x:x + 2]) for x in range(0, len(s), 2)])
```